# How to solve Compatibility Test Suite errors?

Tags: android, cts

I am trying to solve a bunch of errors that were faced while installing AOSP 6.0 Marshmallow on a Tablet. The tablet used to run Windows on it and now I am trying to install Android to it. I need to figure out how to solve the errors that were given by the CTS results. Below is the snippet of few of the errors ==>
[Errors of CTS test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M48cI.jpg)

Comment: The best approach is to do it one by one.

Comment: what I mean to ask is, how do I debug these errors?

Answer (score 1):

Try running with these flags:

```
./cts-tradefed run commandAndExit cts --logcat-on-failure --bugreport-on-failure --screenshot-on-failure --log-level-display debug
```